# Glass Mapper - fluent vs attribute mapping; difference in behavior between inherited SitecoreChildren field

Tags: glass-mapper

I have the following model

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace Ignition.Foundation.Core.Models.BaseModels
{
    public interface INeedsChildren : IModelBase
    {
        IEnumerable<IModelBase> BaseChildren { get; set; }
    }
}
public interface IPage :  IMetadata, INavigation, ITaxonomy, INeedsChildren, IModelBaseWithMetadata, INeedsParent     {   }

public interface IIgnitionPage : IPage  {   }
```

Using AttributeMapping, the BaseChildren had the [SitecoreChildren] attribute.

I have an **`IPage`** model that implemented **`INeedsChildren`**, and that was in turn implemented by **`IIgnitionPage`**.

When using Attribute mapping, this worked as expected, and when I got a page reference I had the children.

Using Fluent mapping, I have the following mappers:

```
using Glass.Mapper.Sc.Maps;
using Ignition.Foundation.Core.Contracts;
using Ignition.Foundation.Core.Models.BaseModels;
namespace Ignition.Foundation.Core.Installers.Mappers
{
    public class NeedsChildrenMap : SitecoreGlassMap<INeedsChildren>, IGlassSettingsConsumer
    {
        public override void Configure()
        {
            Map(x =>
            {
                x.AutoMap().Cachable();
                ImportMap<IModelBase>();
                x.TemplateId(SettingsFactory.GetSitecoreSetting("Ignition.Map.Id.ModelBase"));
                x.Children(a => a.BaseChildren).InferType();
            });
        }

        public ISitecoreSettingsFactory SettingsFactory { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And the IgnitionPageMapper

```
public class IgnitionPageMapper : SitecoreGlassMap<IIgnitionPage>, IGlassSettingsConsumer
    {
        public override void Configure()
        {
            Map(x =>
            {
                ImportMap<IPage>();
                x.AutoMap().Cachable();
                x.TemplateId(SettingsFactory.GetSitecoreSetting("Ignition.Feature.Core.Map.Id.IgnitionPage"));
            });
        }
        public ISitecoreSettingsFactory SettingsFactory { get; set; }
    }
```

And the Page Mapper

```
public class PageMapper : SitecoreGlassMap<IPage>, IGlassSettingsConsumer
    {
        public override void Configure()
        {
            Map(x =>
            {
                ImportMap<IMetadata>();
                ImportMap<INavigation>();
                ImportMap<ITaxonomy>();
                ImportMap<INeedsChildren>();
                ImportMap<INeedsParent>();
                ImportMap<IModelBaseWithMetadata>();
                x.AutoMap().Cachable();
                x.TemplateId(SettingsFactory.GetSitecoreSetting("Ignition.Map.Id.Page"));
            });
        }
        public ISitecoreSettingsFactory SettingsFactory { get; set; }
    }
```

Once I use Fluent mapping, I no longer get BaseChildren of my items. I DO get Parent however, and it is wired up the same way. Am I missing something here, or is this a bug in Glass?

Comment: Jon you can get around this by running a query instead of using .Children in the mean time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So after discussing with Nathanael Mann, it appears that this is indeed a defect in the Mapping code in Glass and not an issue with the implementation. I'll be adding a defect on the Github page and closing this question with this answer.

Answer (score 1):

After playing with this for a bit I found out that if you name the Property Children then it'll work.

Not ideal, but if you are intent on using Fluent mapping and willing to adhere to that naming then it'll get you there.